# App is running on background warning on foreground service on Oreo devices

Tags: android

Title is pretty self-explanatory. For those who don't know, there is an annoying warning that Android Oreo devices have, that if an app runs on background, there is a persistent notification that notifies you about the app running in "background".

On our application, we are using a long-living service with a notification, by calling `Context.startForegroundService(intent)` and this is how we create the notification inside the service:

```
// Check if the device has Oreo as its lowest OS. Same thing with Build.VERSION_CODES check.
if (Helper.ATLEAST_OREO)
{
    // Get notification service.
    NotificationManager notifManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Old notification channel handling.
    NotificationChannel oldChannel = notifManager.getNotificationChannel("old_channel");
    if (oldChannel != null)
        notifManager.deleteNotificationChannel("old_channel");

    // Get new channel.
    NotificationChannel channel = notifManager.getNotificationChannel("new_channel");
    if (channel == null)
    {
        // If null, create it without sound or vibration.
        channel = new NotificationChannel("new_channel", "new_name",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription("some_description");
        channel.enableVibration(false);
        channel.setSound(null, null);
        notifManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    // Create builder.
    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "new_channel");

    // Create a pending intent to redirect to startup activity.
    intent = new Intent(this, StartUpActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setAction("fromNotification"); // for logging purposes
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    // Generate notification.
    builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))  // required
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon_white) // required
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.notification_description))  // required
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    // Start foreground service.
    startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, builder.build());
}
```

Everything is good. The service also have a thread that loops continuously in-between 100 milliseconds interval, while the screen is on. (We are detecting the change with a screen on-off broadcast receiver and start-finish the thread accordingly while the service continues to run.)

However, on Oreo devices user can go to notification settings manually and remove the ongoing notification as it takes space while the service is running (which is all the time in this case). After user removes notifications of the app, when some time passes a notification pops up that says "App is running on the background." with an IGNORE option, that the user will question "what is this app doing?" while it's doing what they asked for.

How can we prevent this from happening? Any help is appreciated, thank you so much.